# Extracting numbers from file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have a txt file " 80 50 65 100 2 35 1 " and i need to add each number in a Var or even better all of them in an array.
like ...

var1=80
   var2=50

or

array[0]=80

.by the way the number after that must be functional . I mean i need to be able to 
     sum= $var1 +$var2 
for example. 
Is there a way to do that ? Thank you!!

Comment: Are they all on one line or on multiple lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your numbers are all on a line, use `read`

```
read -a array < numbers.txt
```

If they're on multiple lines you can change the end of line delimiter like this

```
read -d'\0' -a array < numbers.txt
```

And now you have an array

```
printf 'Number: %s\n' "${array[@]}"
```

Oh yeah, and summing. Lots of ways once you have an array, but how about

```
printf '%s + ' "${array[@]}" | xargs -I{} echo {} 0 | bc
```

Or do it all in one process

```
for n in "${array[@]}" ; do let sum+=$n ; done ; echo $sum
```

Comment: the numbers in my file are in multiple lines so i used read -d'\0' -a array < numbers.txt   .  But when i try to print the array it does nothing...

Comment: To print an array, do `echo "${array[@]}"`

Answer (score 2):

In bash, you can say

```
array=( $(< numbers.txt) )
sum=$( IFS=+; echo "${array[*]}" | bc )
```

Answer (score 1):

So if you have a file `nums.dat` like

```
80 50 65 100 2 35 1
```

You can read these into an array with

```
read -a MYARRAY < nums.dat
```

If you have a much older `bash` or even `ksh` then it was something like (can't remember exactly sorry)

```
set -A MYARRAY $(cat nums.dat)
```